# How to create an Internet-independent Debian installation ISO file

Tags: debian, networking, system-installation, internet, iso

I am trying to create an ISO file for Debian Buster installations, but I need it to be independent of internet connection (standalone) to complete the installation.

I also don't care about desktop version or even existence of desktop environment. A terminal is fine.

To help you formulate any answers, I have some experience as a power-user with Unix (filesystem structure, bash etc) and my internet connectivity is good so downloading anything (Debian DVDs, tools or whatever else) is not a problem.

Also, the ISO file must fit in a 16 Gb flash drive and finish installation (even with minimum packages) without internet connection, there are no other restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The first DVD](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/) of any non-network-install set will allow you to install Debian without accessing the Internet. If you don’t want a desktop environment, make sure none is selected in the package selection step of the installation.

To build your own, custom, installation image, give [Simple-CDD](https://wiki.debian.org/Simple-CDD) a shot; it’s a simple tool which takes a selection of packages and builds an installation CD. If your requirements are more complex, see [the Debian custom CD page](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD) on the Debian wiki.